# Running .py files from a .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple AFK script for if I need to leave my pc for short period and the code works on it's own but when I try to use one script to run another, It runs but then stops a few seconds later with exit code 0. I'm not sure what's wrong and I've tried multiple things such as:

```py
import test1
test1.run()
```

And that doesn't seem to work. Every site I find tells me to use the above example or stuff such as [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) which I've been told is dangerous. Note: a text file named 'bridge' will have to be created so the file can be stopped
main.py

```py
import os
from output import run
import keyboard
from time import sleep
print('Start afk program? (Y/N)')
cmd = str.lower(input('> '))
if cmd == 'y':
    print('Use X to Stop')
    print('Starting in 10 seconds...')
    run()
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            print('exit key pressed')
            x = '1'
        else:
            x = '0'
        if os.path.exists('bridge.txt'):
            with open('bridge.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(x)
                file.write('\n')
                file.close()
        else:
            exit('file not found')
        if x == '1':
            exit(0)
        sleep(0.1)
```

output.py

```py
import os
from time import sleep
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
keyboard = Controller()


def run():
    global keyboard
    sleep(10)
    keyboard = Controller()
    count = 0
    while True:
        if os.path.exists('bridge.txt'):
            with open('bridge.txt', 'r') as file:
                content = file.readlines()
                for line in content:
                    if line[0] == '1':
                        exit(0)
        if count == 1:
            press_key('w')
        elif count == 2:
            press_key('a')
        elif count == 3:
            press_key('s')
        elif count == 4:
            press_key('d')
        elif count == 10:
            count = 0
            press_key('q')
        count += 1
        sleep(0.1)


def press_key(key):
    keyboard.press(key)
    sleep(0.5)
    keyboard.release(key)


run()
```

I get that having the two systems apart can be easily avoided and will be fixed later, but the answer to this question will help me with other projects

Comment: Why are you calling `run()` in `output.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me (Python 3.8), your code works fine if you simply type on the terminal

```
python main.py
```

provided that you comment out or delete the last line in `output.py`:

```
# run()
```

which would execute function `run` upon importing `output` in `main`. The program also works if I import from a local module

```
import output                                                                                           
output.run()
```

If for some reason you're trying to import `output` from a different directory, you may have to deal with relative imports -- a subject nothing to do with the specific implementation of your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to have couple of problems from initial check.
Since you are calling `run()` before the `if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):`, it will always run in infinite loop.

Also, `if line[0] == '1':`, this needs to be changed to `if line[-1] == '1':` to check the last character entered, but since the code never reached the line to take `x` as input, entering a value `x` will not work either.

There are logical errors here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, `line[0]` takes the first character in the string which is what is intended. Although I think I see what you mean in that `if line[0] == '1':` won't be reached. The Intended result was that both scripts would work simultaneously without stopping the other, Do you know if I can adjust the code to get this result?